# PHP - Add value to comma based string/array

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I am storing some data in my database in a comma based string like this:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4 etc...
```

This is the variables for the string:

```
$data["subscribers"];
```

I have a function which on users request can remove their value from the string **or** add it.

This is how I remove it:

```
    /* Remove value from comma seperated string */
    function removeFromString($str, $item) {
    $parts = explode(',', $str);

    while(($i = array_search($item, $parts)) !== false) {
        unset($parts[$i]);
    }

    return implode(',', $parts);
    }
    $newString = removeFromString($existArr, $userdata["id"]);
```

So in the above example, I am removing the $userdata['id'] from the string (if it exists).

**My problem is.. how can I add a value to the comma based string?**

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find it quite surprising that you can come up with the logic for `removeFromString` but is unable to do so for `addToString`.

Comment: @light I like how you think :-0

Comment: This really isn't a good idea.... storing comma-separated values in a database always causes so many problems for people

Comment: @MarkBaker what kind Of problems?

Comment: Precisely the problems you're having: adding, modifying and deleting values from the set..... not to mention searching for records that have a specific value among the set of comma-separated values in that column (find me all the records that user 3 subscribes to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$array[] = $var;` simply do:

```
function addtoString($str, $item) {
    $parts = explode(',', $str);
    $parts[] = $item;

    return implode(',', $parts);
    }
    $newString = addtoString($existArr, $userdata["id"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Best performance for me

```
function addItem($str, $item) {
    return ($str != '' ? $str.',' : '').$item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addToString($str, $item) {
    $parts = explode(',', $str);
    array_push($parts, $str);
    return implode(',', $parts);
}
$newString = addToString($existArr, $userdata["id"]);
```

Comment: The function name should be `addToString`

Comment: Cool, from the version i proposed, just a minor change is needed to be done

Comment: **Note:** If you use `array_push() `to add one element to the array it's better to use `$array[] =` because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function